# Automatically start screen recording on iPhone 13

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-capture

The native iPhone 13 screen record function always counts down 3,2,1 before it starts, and requires manual activation.

Is there a way to auto start the screen record whenever the phone is unlocked and in use? Perhaps, upon phone unlock, the user can be given dialog box that can ask the user if he wants to start the screen record, and if he chooses yes, the screen record starts immediately and not after counting 3,2,1.

Comment: Are you open to 3rd party applications? Even then, I suspect there is no app that just starts recording your screen as soon as you unlock it. I wonder why you need that, it's a big security/privacy concern. It would make sense to have an app that would start recording once tapped without the countdown.

Comment: @elegantcomplexity yes I am open. "an app that would start recording once tapped without the countdown" might suffice.